# How to get the object values inside the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, object

```py
TEAMS = {
    'teamA': {'name': "Brazil",'points': 0,'goals_for': 0,'goals_difference': 0,'goals_against': 0,},
    'teamB': {'name': "Germany",'points': 0,'goals_for': 0,'goals_difference': 0,'goals_against': 0,},
}

MATCHES = [
    {'home': TEAMS['teamA'], 'goalsHome': 0, 'away': TEAMS['teamB'], 'goalsAway': 0},
]

def showMatch(match):
  print(f"Team {match[home][name]} X {match[away][name]} Team")


showMatch(MATCHES)
```

I've this list of dictionaries and the dictionary, 'home' is the 'teamA' object that have 'name', 'points'... and I wanna get the home name.

The output wanted of the print in the showMatch() function is:

```py
Team Brazil X Germany Team
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**. First off, are you trying to figure out *how to do something*, or are you trying to figure out *what is wrong with the code*? Because these are completely different questions that need to be approached differently.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

```py
def showMatch():
    for match in MATCHES:
        print(f"{match['home']['name']} {match['goalsHome']} X {match['goalsAway']} {match['away']['name']}\n")

showMatch()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

Use a loop.

```
for match in MATCHES:
    showMatch(match)
```

BTW, in Python that's a list of dictionaries, not an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks, that's worked, however I trying to print like this print(f"Team " ${[home][name]} "X" ${[away][name]} "Team").

Comment: Why are you using `${}` around the variables? The way you're doing it in the question is correcet.